# Java interface classes?

Tags: java, api, interface

So, I am trying to learn how the interface classes in Java Work, and i'm really confused about it.

I wan't to make it like a method in a normal class file like this:

```
public class APIClass {
    private int davs;

    public int setInt(int dav) {
        this.davs = dav;
        return davs;
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return davs;
    }
}
```

Two methods. One that set's the int "davs", and one getting the int "davs".

What i wan't to do in the interface is something like that. I have seen in others interface files, that they have something like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    public MyInterface setInt(int davs);
    public MyInterface getInt();

}
```

**EDIT:**
My question is that i can't see what i can use the interface for? All i have seen use it, declare the same method in a new class file, and then they really don't need the interface file. So what is it for?

Comment: Note that setters shouldn't return value, they only *set* it. Also please ask a question, you only mentioned facts :/

Comment: Why changing the return type to `MyInterface`? Just use `public int setInt(int davs)`.

Comment: What Java version are you using? Java 8 would result in a different answer than lower versions.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, well, it could be reasonable were setter returns the *previous* value.

Comment: @TagirValeev *Usually* they don't, it's a convention. Unless specified otherwise in the docs, I guess..

Comment: [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) is the general principle around 'read' or 'side-effect' but not both - `getters / setters` should generally observe this principle. There are however exceptions such as stack pops and dequeueing.

Comment: All of this aside, what is the question?

Comment: Right now i'm using Java 8.
I changed it to return a int instead.
When i implements the interface to a class it want me to import all the "methods" i have made in the interface class.
So now my interface is look like this:
http://pastebin.com/gct72g2z
and my class is looking like this:
http://pastebin.com/nReuwZaA

But now i don't need the interface file anymore?

Comment: @The Pc Luddite you can see my question in my edit :)

Comment: You should google for **design patterns** to learn about interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces in Java are meant as an abstraction. You're expected to use it strictly for deriving other classes. You don't declare any methods in it all.

So if you have an interface like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {   
    int setInt(int davs); // this should probably return void
    int getInt();
}
```

And you implement it in a class like this:

```
public class APIClass implements MyInterface {

    private int da;

    public int setInt(int davs) {
       // return da; <- this doesn't make a whole lot of sense
       da = davs; // I assume you meant this
       return da; // usually you don't return anything from a setter
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return dada;
    }
}
```

And another class like this:

```
public class SecondAPIClass implements MyInterface {

    private int dada = 0;

    public int setInt(int davs) { // note that you have to keep the same method signiture in all derived classes
        dada = davs + 5;
        return dada;
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return da;
    }
}
```

You can use the interface to group them both. This is an important part of object oriented design. It's usefulness is probably too long to explain in a simple StackOverflow question, but here's a simple example of its usefullness:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     APIClass first = new APIClass();
     SecondAPIClass second = new SecondAPIClass();
     first.setInt(20);
     second.setInt(20);

     ArrayList<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
     list.add(first);
     list.add(second);

     for(MyInterface item : list) {
          System.out.println(item.getInt());
     }
}
```

The output should be this:

```
 20
 25
```

---

This example might be more helpful:

Consider you have several vehicles. All vehicles can drive, but driving a boat is different from driving a car, or a helicopter. This is where interfaces are useful. You can declare what a `Vehicle` should do, without dictating how it should do it.

```
public interface Vehicle {   
        void drive();
}
```

So when you derive it in a class `Car`, you can state how you want this vehicle to drive.

```
public class Car implements Vehicle {
        void drive() {
             // drive like a car
        }
}
```

Now boats are vehicles, and they can drive too, but driving a boat is much different than driving a car.

```
public class Boat implements Vehicle {
        public void drive() {
               // drive like a boat
        }
}
```

In summary, interfaces are useful when you have an abstract concept in mind, where you know what derived objects should do but can't dictate how they do it.

Comment: What i don't understand about this, is that it also Work without the interface class file?

Comment: @CasperRasmussen No. It won't work. Notice that I created an `ArrayList` of `MyInterface`. Now you can have two different classes with different but similar implementations together.

Comment: Ohh.... i see...

I tried to copy+paste that into my own but it just gives me this: APIClass@659e0bfd

EDIT: i did not see the item.getInt()